# How to represent arbitrary logical expressions in a many to many relationship?

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I have a `Course` entity in my database and I want to represent its prerequisites.

- A `Course` can have many prerequisites.
- A `Course` can be a prerequisite for many other `Course`s
- Clearly, this would be represented as a Many to Many relationship between the `Course` entity and itself.
- But I also need to represent more complicated prerequisites that involve logical expressions. For example `course1` might have the following prerequisites: `course2` AND (`course3` OR `course4`). I need to keep track of the expression and the order of the operands as well.

One approach I thought about is to treat the expression as a product of sums. I would have a `PrerequisiteGroup` entity which represents a group of courses ORed together and then a `Prerequisite` many-to-many relationship to represent a group of `PrerequisiteGroups` ANDed together for every course.

I feel this design might be too complicated when it comes to querying but I think it can represent any logical expression that only has AND and OR operators. Please let me know if there are better designs. Also, let me know if a relational database isn't the best to represent this, and if a graph-based database would be simpler.